# Unable to toggle Global Navigation on, can not see or access the setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, global-navigation, sharepoint-app-bar

I would like to toggle Global Navigation on, but I do not see the option on my intranet home site.

I am the Site Owner.  I also checked with the Global Admin and he also cannot see the option, so I assume it is a bug.  Has anyone else had this experience?

[image: Screen shot of intranet home page, no Global Setting option visible]

Here is a [relevant Microsoft link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-app-bar#get-started-customizing-the-global-navigation-tab) on the topic of toggling on Global Navigation (left of the screen).

I am able to customize the top bar navigation, but it is the navigation on the left I am focusing on.

Comment: Are you using [Standard release or targeted release](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365) on your tenant?

Comment: We're using Standard release

Comment: Did you set up a home site? check my answer below & follow the steps. It should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set up a home site in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/set-up-a-home-site-in-sharepoint-online/) to enable and customize the [global navigation in SharePoint app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/).

Once you set up a home site, you can see the global navigation settings on home site like:

[image]

Follow below blogs for more information related to SharePoint app bar, home site & enabling/customizing global navigation in app bar:

1. [Set up a home site in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/set-up-a-home-site-in-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Enable and Customize Global navigation](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/04/enable-and-customize-global-navigation-in-the-sharepoint-app-bar/) in [SharePoint app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, running the powershell script worked, thank you for your helpful answer.  It was a curious case, as my home site is the OOTB home site that is provisioned when the SPO tenancy is set up.